# Python - adding all elements of list via for loop in a Custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I'm new here, I'm recently started learning python, So I want to create a function that can sum of all elements of list using For loop in function, below is what i written:

```
# Function for sum of all elements of list
def my_num(number):
    count = 0
    for numbers in number:
        count = count + numbers
        # return count
my_list = list(range(1, 2, 3, 4))
print(my_num(my_list))
```

It's Printing - `None`

I suppose to adding all numbers of my_list using the function `my_num`

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `my_list = list(range(1, 2, 3, 4))` is wrong and `my_list = list(range(1, 4))` works fine for me

Comment: Your `# return count` should be unindented one level (brought outside the `for` loop), and not be a comment (remove the `#`).

Comment: You can also use inbuilt function for sum `sum(range(1,5))`

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python list sum", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  Research before you post.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, there is no `return` statement at the end of the function. Any function without a `return` statement returns `None`.

```
def my_num(number):
    count = 0
    for num in number:
        count += num
    return count
my_list = list(range(1, 5)) # range(start, end)
print(my_num(my_list)) # -> 10
```

Alternatively, Python already has a built-in function: `sum()` which returns the sum of any list of numbers.

```
my_list = list(range(1, 5))
print(sum(my_list)) # -> 10
```

Also, `range()` only takes 3 arguments: `start, end, step`. The correct way to get `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is to use `range(1, 5)`, where `1` is inclusive and `5` is exclusive.

Comment: you do not need to convert range into list. sum expects an iterator and does not necessarily mean it needs a list

Comment: Hi Firend, Thanks for quick response.
I completely agree with you, without returns statement output will be None, Actually I was written return statement that was also not working, but suddenly I see return statement in your code  and compared with mine, I found that indentation for return statement was wrong, there was 8 spaces before return statement, I just removed 4 extra spaces and got the answer correct as I wanted.